# Is it correct to use the number sign # on the header of a table in scientific papers in formal written American English to replace "number of"?

Tags: american-english

Is it correct to use the hashtag/pound sign/number sign # on table headers in scientific papers written in American English to replace the words "number of"?

For example: Let's say we have a table with a row for each country of the world and a header column that says "inhabitants#" rather than "number of inhabitants".

Is this use of the number sign "#" accepted in the mentioned context of scientific papers in formal written American English?

If it is accepted,  should it be "inhabitants#" or "inhabitant#"?

Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia tends to use "population" rather than "number of inhabitants" or "inhabitants" as a table column heading in entries such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cities) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-level_administrative_divisions_by_area).

Comment: What wouldn't you use the standard sign for this, `№`?

Comment: @tchrist I'm surprised to hear that suggestion from an American - we seem to use it much more this side of the Atlantic.  But to suggest one answer for your rhetorical question, perhaps because it's missing in a lot of fonts so a fallback font is used which might be a poor match to the surrounding text possibly without even being clear (as in the font used to display it with code markup here - `№`). The default font is marginally better - №.

Answer (score 3):

It's just possible your target journal will have a style guide covering this, or at least unnecessary use of abbreviations (which is close enough).

Even writing in American English, you're writing for an international audience, so if this isn't common in your field, it's not very helpful. # as a number sign isn't universal. Even in British English, "no." is far more common, though this use of a hash is understood and growing (much more so than when the same symbol is used to denote pounds weight).

In your examples, you should probably have a space, but more importantly, "inhabitant #" is ambiguous. Does it mean "number of inhabitants"? Or does it mean "inhabitant number" (as in an ID or index number)? I don't seem to be alone in finding this the more obvious meaning.

If I was going to use a # (which is unlikely), I'd use "# of inhabitants" as a 2-line heading with the line break after "of". That's narrower than your unspaced version, and width is nearly always the issue when laying out tables. But once you go to 2 lines, you may as well say "number of inhabitants" because it's clearer to your whole audience in the same space.

Comment: It should be emphasised that even an audience that is quite familiar with how this sign is used in North America, is more likely to interpret 'inhabitant #' as some sort of an identification number, than the number **of** inhabitants.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a matter of opinion, and the one that matters is that of the journal. For what it’s worth, mine is:

1. The first thing to do is to look at other articles in your chosen journal to see if the # abbreviation you propose is in common use, or even whether you can find any examples at all. If, as I suspect it is not, don’t use it. My area of science is different, but I’ve never seen it used.
2. Consider alternatives for saving space in your table headings. Using:

> No. Inhabitants

…is common, but do you actually need to represent “number” explicitly. Writing:

> Inhabitants

…alone is probably unambiguous if the entries are all numbers.

*or:*

> Population

…if this is appropriate. An asterisk could be added, if necessary, indicating a footnote that gave more detail.

Comment: +1. Do scientific journals ever use simple A-Z column labels with a key explaining that column "A" is the "number of inhabitants"?

Comment: @TimR Not in my experience. The argument against is one of communication —  it makes reading the table more difficult. Tables, in any case, are more difficult to absorb than figures, but are necessary where complex data does not lend itself to a graph format. One can, however, abbreviate headings and use labels with a key as you suggest.

Comment: I now see @StuartF suggested population in a comment after my original answer and before my update (this morning in a different time zone) to include this.

Comment: @David yes, I'm also (in physics) used to seeing table headers that might be as compact as possible, but that are meaningful in themselves. Table notes are useful to provide further explanation. If really narrow columns are needed, running the header text vertically seems to be the least worst option